# Apache Netbeans - Maven Web Project - Tomcat Server Error

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I followed a very basic project creation tutorial here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eP9oz6ZKUXM

Here's what I did:

**1) Install Apache Tomcat Server**

- Download and install Apache Tomcat: https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.2/bin/apache-tomcat-10.0.2.exe
- I selected the type of install as "Full"
  [image]
- I set the Server Shutdown Port as "8005"

[image]

- I pointed it to JDK15 (JRE 1.8 was default as that is also on the machine)

[image]

**2) Add the server to Apache Netbeans IDE**

[image]
[image]

**3) Create Maven Web App using Tomcat Server**

[image]
[image]

4. Add Servlet and edit index.html

[image]

**Servlet Code:**

```
   /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package fourc.group.mavenwebautomation;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author DagninE
 */
@WebServlet(name = "UnitConverterServlet", urlPatterns =
{
    "/MavenWebAutomation/convert"
})
public class UnitConverterServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        float miles = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("miles"));
        float km = miles * 1.6f;

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try ( PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
        {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Unit Conversion Result</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Conversion Result</h1>");
            out.println("<p>" + miles + " miles = " + km + " kilometers </p>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.html Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Maven Project</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <h1>Unit Converter</h1>
            <form action="convert" method="post">
                Miles : <input type="number" name="miles" required/>
                <input type="submit" value="Convert to km"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**6) Run the app**

No here is where 2 things happen:

**First - Two Chrome tabs open (I cannot understand WHY):**

[image]

**Second - When I attempt to do the conversion, I get an error:**
[image]
[image]

I honestly have zero clue why this is the way it is. In theory, everything should work?

Comment: Probably you are using `javax.servlet` instead of `jakarta.servlet`: that's the main change between Tomcat 9 and Tomcat 10.

Comment: Please, add the source code as text, not images and include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): out of your very long question composed mostly by images, only the servlet code (with import statements), HTML file and server version are relevant to the issue.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Alright, thank you. Just give me a moment to update the question please.

I will check the link you provided now.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thank you for the help on this. The link you provided (along with your comment on the import) is what the issue was. I don't believe I had the correct context in my search criteria when I Googled. Also, being that the tutorial was only done in December, I did not think something would be broken in the basic setup of it. Nevertheless, thank you again! :)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Do you perhaps know why 2 Chrome tabs open when I run the code?